# Java playing sounds. Is there a default system sound?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

Hi I am trying to write an application that will play morse code. I just wanted to know if there was a default system sound in java like some beep, or do I have to download some sound file from the internet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can:

Print the ASCII bell character to the console (will emit a beep sound):

```
public class DoBeep {
    public static main(String args[]) {
        System.out.print("\007"); // bell ASCII char
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
```

Use the `beep()` method that will use the buzzer on the motherboard:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class DoBeep {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();     
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of system.out.flush(); ?

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart See the Javadoc for [`PrintStream#flush`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#flush()). The output bytes may be buffered rather than sent immediately to the underlying output stream. Calling `flush` forces any buffered content to be sent immediately, hence the metaphorical method name “flush”.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Java Sound API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/), which can play MIDI tones.

Comment: There's been discussion of removing the MIDI output capabilities in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [jMorse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmorse/) for some tips. This isn't to discourage you from your effort, but rather to provide a reference.